# Dynamically Declare Start/End Dates From Current Month

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, datetime

I have a pretty basic query that I run monthly. Every month I have to manually change the query to fit the current month start and end date. I've tried using some of the examples from previous answers but can't seem the make it work. Notably because I am trying to include the entire last day of the month, as shown by my 23:59:59 parameter. What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
SELECT *
FROM WorkOrder
where active = 1 and
WorkOrderStatusId in (6,8) AND
dateCreated >= '5/1/2017' and
dateCreated <= '5/31/2017 23:59:59'
```

Comment: which sql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things:

First: dates look like `2017-05-01` not `5/1/2017` in most DBMS representations.

Second:  you want this sort of expression (note the `<`) to make sure you get all rows. That's a better approach than the `23:59:59` stuff.

```
where  dateCreated >= '2017-05-01'
  and  dateCreated <  '2017-06-01'
```

Third, you probably want a way of saying

```
 where dateCreated >= first_day_of_last_month
   and dateCreated <  first_day_of_this_month
```

in a way where you don't have to change the query every month.

This works differently in different makes and models of database server. You didn't tell us which one you're using, so...

In MS SQL Server, `DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE())` gives you the first of the present month, so

```
where dateCreate >= 
         DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
  and dateCreate < 
         DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
```

In MySQL `DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')` gives you midnight on the first day of the present month, so this `where` clause gets last month's rows.

```
where dateCreated >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  and dateCreated <  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')
```

In Oracle (cue *if I were a rich man* from *Fiddler on the Roof*)  `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')` gives you the first of the month, so this gets last month's rows.

```
where dateCreate >= ADD_MONTHS(-1, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'))
  and dateCreate <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response! I am using Microsoft SQL. I apologize for not mentioning, I always assumed if I didn't specify MySQL (which is Linux, right?) that MS SQL was the default. I don't know much about databases, so I appreciate the information. I'll be sure to specify in the future :)

Comment: It's helpful to the community if you check the green checkbox when an answer solves your problem.  MySQL and Oracle both run on Windows / Linux / FreeBSD. MySQL also runs on Mac. Microsoft SQL Server runs on Windows only (they have a prototype Linux version).

Answer (score 0):

what you can actually do is get the month and year

```
SELECT *
FROM WorkOrder
where active = 1 and
WorkOrderStatusId in (6,8) AND
year(dateCreated) = 2017
month(dateCreated) = 5
```